# Probability question involiving using negative binomial

Tags: probability

An expert sharpshooter misses a target 10 percent of the time.

1. What is the probability that she misses the target for the $2$nd time in her $10$th shot?
2. What is the probability that her $2$nd miss comes no later than her $10$th shot?

I'm fairly certain that these questions require the use of negative binomial distribution formulas. Anyway,

1. so I've calculated (1.) and I believe it's $P(X=10)=0.0387$.
2. As for (2.) I have no idea how to calculate $P(X \leq 10)$. I know I could add $$P(X=1) + P(X=2)+\dots + P(X=10)$$ but there has to be another way.

Comment: First solution looks good.  For the second...you've already computed the probability that there was exactly one miss in the first nine shots, so all you need to do is compute the probability of no misses over those nine shots (the answer is 1 minus the sum of these two).

Comment: Fo b), do you essentially want the probability of at least 2 failures in 10 trials? Then what you need is to consider the probability of either 0 or 1 failures in 10 trials and subtract it from 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the binomial distribution instead with parameters $n=10$ and $p=10\%$. Specifically, the number of misses $Y$ in the first $n=10$ shots is binomially distributed with parameters $n=10$ and $p$ as above, i.e. $p=10\%$. Then the probability that the second miss comes no later than the $10$-th shot is equal to the probability that there are at least two misses in the first $10$ shots. Hence you want to calculate \begin{align}P(Y\ge 2)&=1-P(Y<2)\\[0.2cm]&=1-P(Y=0)-P(Y=1)\\[0.2cm]&=1-\dbinom{10}{0}(0.10)^0(1-0.10)^{10}-\dbinom{10}{1}(0.10)^1(1-0.10)^{10-1}\end{align}

Comment: Ohh, thanks a lot